# Диалоговое окно перед выходом из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Пользователь заходит на фрагмент, на котором может изменить данные. На панели инструментов есть кнопка Up

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При ее нажатии я хочу спросить у пользователя нужно ли  сохранить изменения. Вот как я это начал делать.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: //нажата кнопка Up
                if(!isChanged){     //Проверяю изменил ли пользователь данные на этой странице
                    break;   //Если нет - то ничего сохранять не нужно - просто выходим
                }
                // Если да - то спрашиваем нужно ли сохранить изменения
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogExit = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                dialogExit.setMessage("Сохранить изменения перед выходом?");
                dialogExit.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        savePoster();
                    }
                });
                dialogExit.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                dialogExit.show();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Почти работает. Проблема в том, что диалоговое окно выводится буквально на одну секунду и не ждет моего ответа. Фрагмент сразу закрывается. Скажите пожалуйста, как мне изменить код, чтобы фрагмент не закрывался, а ждал пока я отвечу диалоговому окну?

---

Не понимаю что сложного я тут нашел но когда на свежую голову взглянул на свой вопрос, то сам себе на него ответил за 30 секунд...

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: //нажата кнопка Up
        if(!isChanged){     //Проверяю изменил ли пользователь данные на этой странице
            return false;   //Если нет - то ничего сохранять не нужно - просто выходим
        }
            // Если да - то спрашиваем нужно ли сохранить изменения
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogExit = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialogExit.setMessage("Сохранить изменения перед выходом?");
        dialogExit.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                savePoster();
                exit();
            }
        });
        dialogExit.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                dialog.cancel();
                exit();
            }
        });
        dialogExit.show();
    }
    return true;
}
public void exit(){
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Comment: У вас `Toolbar` отдельно стоит в `Layout`-е ?

Comment: @Iman, как это отдельно?

Comment: Может быть дело в пропущенном `break` в конце `case`?